# Multiple Listboxes, One Selection

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, listbox, selection

I have 2 List Boxes on my form, but I only want to be able to make a single selection between both, how would I go about this?

I, of course, tried doing this first...

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox2.ClearSelected()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox1.ClearSelected()
End Sub
```

But since that causes the selected index to be changed it clears what you have just selected as well...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you can get the selected index from the EventArgs. So you clear both listboxes and then set the last listbox to the data you get from the eventargs AFTER clearing both listboxes.

Comment: That would count as a selection change and create an infinite loop.

Comment: You can check if the set value is cleared, if it's cleared you just set the event as handled. No loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *test the reason* why Selected index changed, something like that:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // If listBox2 focused i.e. user clicked list box2 - do nothing:
  // one should not try to clear list box2 selection
  if (listBox2.Focused)
    return;

  listBox2.ClearSelected();
}

private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  // If list box1 is in focus that means that user just have selected itme there;
  // so, do nothing: we shouldn't erase user's selection 
  if (listBox1.Focused)
    return;

  listBox1.ClearSelected();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your question is tagged as C# but the code sample is in VB.
Second, I would do it in C# as follows:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);
    listBox2.ClearSelected();
    listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged);

}
```

And do the same with the other event handler.